# How do I include an SDK routine in VB6?

Tags: windows, sdk, vb6, windows-xp

I am modifying some old VB6 code and there are a number of calls to a subroutine called `SDKPress(Index as integer, PressStatus as Integer, PressX as double, PressY as double, PressDataX as double, PressDataY as double)`.

(This routine returns the position of the mouse click and Index returns which graph on a form the mouse is in.)

Since there is no code for this in the project, I assume it is from some Windows software development kit. However, there is no trace of it on the development PC. just an SDK directory in the VisualBasic directory containing winsdk_web.exe.

I cannot call that subroutine from another project. Where does the subroutine live? Where can I find documentation on it? How can I get it in a form where I can use it on another project?

Answer (score 1):

**To find out where it lives**. Put the cursor in one of the routine calls in the IDE, right-click on it, and choose `go to definition`. See where it takes you.

- It may be an ordinary routine in a code file in your project.
- It may be a routine in a DLL which is imported into your project via a `Declare` statement.
- It may be a routine in a COM/ActiveX DLL or OCX control or even ActiveX EXE. In which case the IDE will show you the "object browser" window and you should be able to figure out where the routine lives, and go from there. I.e. figure out how to add a reference to it into another VB project, and how to install/register the relevant DLL/OCX/EXE on another PC.

**OR**, and I'm sure you tried this already, but just in case, search the source code for the routine name. Use `Ctr-F` or menu item `Edit-Find` in the VB IDE.

Comment: To add to that: the Object Browser is invoked with F2. You should also check the menu entry Project -> References to see what COM DLLs are added there.

Comment: It's true F2 will always open the Object Browser. I think Shift-F2 (the shortcut to go to definition) will open the Object Browser if that's appropriate for the item under the cursor.  I should say this is all from memory as I don't actually do much hands-on VB6 these days!

Comment: TIL: Shift+F2 does that indeed. After all these decades, there's still stuff to learn.

Comment: Using the Object Browser, I get the answer "Identifier under cursor is not recognized." I can look at other item's definitions and get good answers.

Comment: That's weird. Sorry. If I think of more advice, I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

DLL files contains the API functions, vb6 code will load the DLL (`Declare Function SDKPress Lib "DLLName" ....`) and call the functions, use a tool like DllExpView: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html and list DLLs and their functions. Or it also might be an internal subroutine/function.

Answer (score 0):

If the original program which uses the SDK runs, you can gather some information using Process Monitor and Process Explorer. These can help you locate dependencies of many types.

I'd start with the second - when you run your program, ProcExp will show you all the files, including DLLs, that are loaded into the process. This alone might give you some insight.

If that is insufficient then use ProcMon to actively monitor the activities of your program. While ProcExp is basically a snapshot in time, ProcMon will dynamically record many of the actions of your program, including how it searches for and ultimately loads DLLs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

I have found these tools to be invaluable on many occasions. They help to break down the "black box" around a running process which appears in many programmers minds.

Comment: I found a copy of the Process Monitor that ran on XP and tried it to no avail. Is there a good site to get Process Explorer 16.02 that runs on XP? The newer 64 bit versions won't run.

Comment: Was there a 32 bit version at all?